# How can a MDL menu be made to stay open after clicking in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, material-design-lite

I need to place a input in a MDL menu. The problem is when I click into the input or anything in the menu it closes the menu. How can this be made to work?

This is an example of the problem.

```
   <button id="demo-menu-lower-right"
            class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
      <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
    </button>

    <div class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect"
        for="demo-menu-lower-right">
        <form action="#">
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3" />
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Text...</label>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to hide and show a div instead of using the built in menu. This is not perfect as it does not have animations if some one knows how to make the menu animations work with it or knows how to make the menu work for this I will select that answer.

the fixed code.

HTML

```
<button id="loginbntstoggle"
        class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
  <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
</button>

<div id="loginbnts">
    <form action="#">
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3" />
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Text...</label>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
'click #loginbntstoggle' : function(e){
        if(document.getElementById("loginbnts").style.display=="none"){
            document.getElementById("loginbnts").style.display = "block";
        }else{
            document.getElementById("loginbnts").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

CSS

```
#loginbnts{display:none;}
```